# How do I assign a bug to myself in Launchpad?

Tags: development, launchpad

I'm interested in [fixing a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23714/i-want-to-fix-a-bug-where-do-i-start) in Ubuntu, but I don't want to step on anyone's toes. How do I "claim" a bug to let people know I'm working on it?

(Screenshots of where in Launchpad to click please)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To assign a bug to yourself in Launchpad, first navigate to the bug page (e.g. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/397393 )

[image]

This shows that the bug is not assigned to anyone at the moment. Click on the Unassigned link

[image: Assign dialog]

Finally, click on the Assign Me link (the little yellow exclamation point)

[image]

The bug is now assigned for you to work on it.