# A quick question on fixing bugs in repository software

Tags: eclipse, contributing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want to fix a bug. Where do I start?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23714/i-want-to-fix-a-bug-where-do-i-start)

I want to start getting involved in contributing to ubuntu. I have found a bug in the eclipse package and know how to fix it, so I thought this would be a good first step.

I just want to check if following this workflow is the correct way to fix bugs for ubuntu:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Recipes/PackageUpdate

Thank you for your help

Comment: Ubuntu's how-to page for bugfixes is here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/HowToFix

Comment: oops missed that. Thanks, if you repost it as an answer I will accept it