# How to disable the discrete gpu? I get 'Kernel failure' with the normal method

Tags: 12.04, hybrid-graphics, vgaswitcheroo

I have notebook hp dm3-2015er with two graphic cards.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880M [Mobility Radeon HD 4225/4250]
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430]
```

Both powered.

```
$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:01:05.0
1:DIS: :Pwr:0000:02:00.0
```

But executing of `echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswithceroo/switch` leads to kernel failure or something. I have to shut down by holding power button. I'm new to linux so I don't know where to find messages shown before freezing.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The correct command isn't `OFF` but `IGD`. If you  Exerpt from the [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics#Using_vga_switcheroo):

> Once you've ensured that vga_switcheroo is available, you can use
>   these options to switch between GPUs. Be prepared for a lockup (either
>   immediately, or after a minute), the existence of this file does not
>   mean that the machine is supported.
>
> ```
> echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
> ```
>
> ^ Turns on the GPU that is disconnected (not currently driving outputs),
>   but does not switch outputs.
>
> ```
> echo IGD > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
> ```
>
> ^ Connects integrated graphics with outputs.
>
> ```
> echo DIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
> ```
>
> ^ Connects discrete graphics with outputs.
>
> ```
> echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
> ```
>
> ^ Turns off the graphics card that is currently disconnected.

You should run then `sudo sh -c "echo DIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch"` to switch to the discrete graphics card. For switching back to full power use `sudo sh -c "echo IGD > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch"`.

To look into kernel failures message, you should check the `/var/log/kern.log.0` and `/var/log/dmesg.0`.

Comment: IGD, DIS and ON commands make no effect at all. There are no failure messages in /var/log/*. Also I installed linux-crushdump but it's not catching `oops` for some reason too.

Comment: @user2418306 when you say "no effect" care to elaborate? It shouldn't return anything. If you do `IGD` or `DIS` then `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` then you will notice the change.

Comment: I did `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` after each of three commands but it (output) stays the same. That's what I mean by no effect.

Comment: Do you do the calls starting with `sudo`? The complete command should be `sudo sh -c "echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch"`, replacing `ON` with the desired command.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly so.

Comment: Then that smells like bug to me...

Comment: How can I write a bug report, without failure message?

Comment: I recommend you reading [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/169736) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/23714/169736).