# How do I register as a Ubuntu developer?

Tags: development, launchpad

I want to contribute as a Ubuntu developer, and help out Ubuntu in any way I can, but don't really know where to register as a Ubuntu developer, or what the requirements/steps for being an Ubuntu developer are.

How would I register to become a Ubuntu developer?

Also, when I have registered myself, how do I upload packages?

Related:

- [Expansion of Valve free games offer to Ubuntu developers](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-announce/2014-February/001079.html)

Comment: http://community.ubuntu.com/contribute/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your motivation is only the free Valve games, that is not a quality they are looking for in developers.

In any case, the steps to become an Ubuntu developer are detailed on the [ubuntu website](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2011/01/27/becoming-an-ubuntu-developer-a-short-guide/).

Becoming a Ubuntu Developer entails interacting with the Ubuntu Community and Members, working in the specific area you are interested, then applying to the Ubuntu Developer Membership Board.

A good starting point for package publication is to create a personal package archive and publish packages to it.

See also:

- [I want to fix a bug. Where do I start?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23714/i-want-to-fix-a-bug-where-do-i-start)

Comment: I didn't ask this just for the free games, I asked this because on its own, its a good question. The free games, was just a bonus, future developers might get a kick out of. Feel free to delete it, or don't? BTW, linked answer are - I think - generally not allowed. Best to copy the essentials here. Thanks for the link tho!

Answer (score 0):

The most updated page that describes the different ways to contribute to Ubuntu is [UbuntuDevelopers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopers).

You don't just register and start uploading. You typically start by preparing patches / merge proposals that developers review and upload. That way you gain the necessary experience to apply later on for some type of right to upload by yourself.